# Jeditable - detect ajax error

Tags: jquery, ajax, jeditable

Is there some code I can add to [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) to raise an error if the XHR request I'm using returns something other than HTTP 200 (e.g. if there's an internal server error or the server times out completely)?

I tried adding the callback parameter (below), but it only seems to fire when the AJAX request is successful...

```
   $('.foo').editable('/user/ajax_edit_full_name', 
       {
        indicator: 'Saving...',
        cancel : 'Cancel',
        submit : 'Save',
        cssclass : 'editable',
        callback : function(value, settings) {
             console.log(this);
             console.log(value);
             console.log(settings);
         }
       }
   );
```

**Update:** Further to Bruno's answer, besides the 'status' property, xhr has, amongst other things, `xhr.statusText`.  So in my case, if they specify an empty name (which is invalid) I've set the server to send an error 400 plus a custom message, and the latter is displayed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accordingly to the [Jeditable source code](http://www.appelsiini.net/download/jquery.jeditable.js) there's a parameter called `onerror`

```
@param Function options[onerror]  function(settings, original, xhr) { ... } called on error
```

Thus, it's possible to achieve what you are trying to do by adding the parameter `onerror` on your `editable` function. The `onerror` parameter expects as argument a function in the following format:

```
function(settings, original, xhr) { ... }
```

Where the `xhr` parameter is your `XHR Object`. So, instead of trying to catch the error on your on, you can simply treat then inside your `onerror` function. Like the following:

```
$('.foo').editable('/user/ajax_edit_full_name', 
{
    indicator: 'Saving...',
    cancel : 'Cancel',
    submit : 'Save',
    cssclass : 'editable',
    onerror : function(settings,original,xhr){
        alert("It wasn't possible to edit. Try again");
        console.log("XHR Status: " + xhr.status);
    },
    callback : function(value, settings) {
         console.log(this);
         console.log(value);
         console.log(settings);
     }
});
```

I hope it helped.